# Get element style attribute?

Tags: jquery, css, addclass

I have this HTML code, that I can not edit manually :(

```
<div id="grid" style="width:1435px; position:absolute;"></div>
```

I need some JQuery function to catch that element, and change style width from 1435 to 1000px?

```
.width{
     width:1000px;
}

$('#grid').addclass('width');
```

Does not work, because inline style has priority of styling the element, is it possible to catch that value and change it, tried it with `!important` too, but no luck.

**EXTRA QUESTION?**

I got the correct answer, but i having little issues, it is possible to catch that 1435px, because it always change, and just short it for 50px?

**ANSWER**

```
var divWidthContent= $("#grid")[0].style.width;
$('#grid').css({"width" :  (parseInt( divWidthContent ) - 50 + "px")});
```

Comment: Let me introduce you the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).

Comment: Using !important should definitely work, and overrides inline styles (http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). Have you tried applying the style directly to the grid by using its ID, e.g: #grid { width:1000px !important; }?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should do it

```
 $('#grid').css({"width" : "1000px"});
```

Comment: Txanks mate, but little issue i am having, can you extend the code, i need to catch that 1435px, because it is dinamicly made, and than cut it for 50px, is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**css()**](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
 $('#grid').css('width','1000px');
```

And Additionally, You don't need to prefix class with `.`, Just use class name

```
 $('#grid').addclass('width');
```